# where to placing the ProgressDialog to create loading

Tags: android, loading, progressdialog

hey i want to display a loading progress using `ProgressDialog` on my aplication, but i'm confuse where to place it... here is the ilustration of my code... the code to create a grayscale image...

```
public void but_gray(View v){
    ProgressDialog prog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "tesLoading",true);
    bmp = grayscale(bmp);
    prog.dismiss;
```

}

That's my code, but when i run the code, dose not show the progress dalog...
the but_gray is a function when i click the grayscale button...
bmp is a bitmap variabel..
grayscale() is a function thats create a grayscale image...

anyone can give me solution

Comment: i think it goes so quick that you dont see it!

Comment: @RiNxX-Sarim : hmm.. if i dont add the progressdialog its take few second to progress it.. abaut 3-4 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create asynctask like ,

```
  class Background_task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
  {
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DisplayBooksView.this, null, "Loading..."); 
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        bmp = grayscale(bmp);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

then call this asynctask in your function like,

```
    public void but_gray(View v){
          new Background_task().execute();
    }
```

it will works fine.....

Comment: thx kalandar... i had tried your code and it's work very good... :D